# DataGridView case sensitive search

Tags: c#, postgresql, search, datagridview

an advice would be much appreciated.

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Location")
{
    CRUD.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(
       "SELECT * FROM archive WHERE location LIKE '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%'", CRUD.con);
    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.SelectCommand = CRUD.cmd;
    dt.Clear();
    da.Fill(dt);
    grid.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Here is my code for searching through DataGridView, everything is working fine but its case sensitive. I tried with `txtsearch.Text.ToLower()` but than it doesn't display upper case searches at all, any hints?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) alert!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, I'm kind of new to C# and PostgreSQL, and this is the example code that I found for textbox search and it works just fine when i tested it. Should I do it differently?

Comment: `Like` is case sensitive, `ILike` is case insensitive https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: I'd never imagine that one character would solve my problem *sarcasm*. What a cliché. Thank you very much kind sir! Much appreciated.